# Storage of partially used jar of mustard?

Tags: storage-method, storage, mustard

Because I use mustard for my own consumption only occasionally, I am buying smallest available packages (350 g) but after opening I can see unused mustard slowly changing into "water" and solid component. I understand that every food deteriorates but I would like to understand something more about this.

- Why it does not deteriorate this way in unopened package?
- Is there some advice to slow down the process? Or even a way to simply renew its original consistence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mustard often separates, it doesn't mean it's going bad. It's likely perfectly fine, mustard stays good for years in the refrigerator. Just stir it up before using it to recombine.

As for why it doesn't separate unopened, sometimes it does. Often you are buying a product that's been manufactured recently, so it hasn't had time to separate yet.

Comment: The vinegar content is a great preservative.

Comment: Syneresis, just as in yogurt: http://www.freepatentsonline.com/6461657.html   Give the stuff a stir or shake. It'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the suggestion works great. @WayfaringStranger - thanks for the term.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger, that's a good word, nerd.

Comment: @GdD It shocks people who think they're absorbing positive Chi energy from their blueberry Greek yogurt!

Answer (score 0):

You could go to a restaurant that uses single-serve packets (a fast-food place like McDonalds or a Chinese/Asian restaurant, any place doing takeaway food) and request that the manager/assistant manager sell you a sufficient small quanity of those packets

Comment: The question was *why does it separate*...

Comment: @Stephie Yes, it was! I can read!
I provided a suggested solution to not 'buying smallest available packages (350 g)' apparently available to her
Most everyone knows that many products separate and are intelligent enough to not have to read 'Shake before using' on a label
One would think that detailed scientic replies in explanation are NOT solutions to your perceived problems

Comment: @Stephie – I find this answer to be creative and adding an idea to my mindset so as the OP I upvoted it. I also sometimes have access to cash-and-carry companies where restaurants purchase their ingredients so this answer also reminded me about going this way.